# returning a list of tuples like zip, generate it incrementally a tuple at a time, using comprehensions

Tags: python, generator

I need a function which returns a tuple one at a time from a list of sequences without using zip . i tried to do it in this fashion:

```
gen1=[(x,y)for x in range(3) for y in range(4)]
```

which gives the following list:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
```

next I tried to return one tuple at a time by:

```
next(gen1)
```

But an error occured that list is not 'iterable' . how can i do it using generators.

Comment: Why can't you use `zip`? It seems like a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

As of Python 2.4, you can do:

```
gen1 = ((x, y) for x in range(3) for y in range(4))
```

Note that you can always make a generator (well, iterator) from a list with `iter`:

```
gen1 = iter([(x, y) for x in range(3) for y in range(4)])
```

The difference in usage will be none. The second way will require the whole list to be in memory, though, while the first will not.

Note that you can also use the builtin functionality of `zip`, which is a generator (in Python 3). In Python 2, use `itertools.izip`.

Python 3:

```
>>> zip(range(0, 5), range(3, 8))
<zip object at 0x7f07519b3b90>
>>> list(zip(range(0, 5), range(3, 8)))
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7)]
```

Python < 3:

```
# Python < 3
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> izip(range(0, 5), range(3, 8))
<itertools.izip object at 0x7f5247807440>
>>> list(izip(range(0, 5), range(3, 8)))
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7)]
>>> zip(range(0, 5), range(3, 8))
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7)]
```

Comment: but I have to generate the above list of tuples by using this function:'def generator_zip(seq1, seq2, *more_seqs):'How can I generate the generator when there are more than two sequences..??@Noctua

Comment: @user3226258: That's exactly what `zip` does. It's a generator.

Comment: @Noctua `zip` is NOT a generator.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: Yes it is? Unless of course you're still using Python 2. Then you'll have to import `itertools.izip`.

Comment: @Noctua I am in fact still using Python 2, which is also implied in your answer.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: Myeah, I did :P. I've included this all in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the behavior to work with an arbitrary number of sequences, while there are still some ambiguities in the question, if what you're trying to do is just make a generator version  of zip, the below should work well:

```
def generator_zip(*args):
    iterators = map(iter, args)
    while iterators:
        yield tuple(map(next, iterators))
```

First it turns each arg into an iterator, then continues to yield tuple that include the next relevant entry from each iterator until the shortest list is exhausted.

Comment: It would be strange if this was his actual question, because this is exactly what `zip` does...

Comment: I tried it but it is giving the following result:'def generator_zip(seq1, seq2, *more_seqs):
    iterators = map(iter,more_args)
    while iterators:
        yield tuple(map(next,iterators))
    pass
>>> generator_zip(range(5), range(3), range(4), range(5))
<generator object generator_zip at 0x00DB3B48>'@Slater Tyranus

Comment: @Noctua it actually isn't. This returns a generator version of the zipped contents, which allows you to lazily load large lists without running into memory issues.

Comment: @user3226258 Yes, it's a generator. As you indicated in your question you were looking for an answer where you would run the `next` method to return the next item. Try running `a = generator_zip(range(5), range(4)); a.next()`

Comment: @user3226258 The above function has an output nearly identical to that of `izip`

Comment: How can I implement the following function: 'def generator_zip(seq1, seq2, *more_seqs:' the problem is it is not returning the tuples in the corrct way EX:if i pass 'generator_zip(range(5), range(3), range(4),range(5))' and ask next(gen) it says '(0,0)' instaed of '(0,0,0,0)' as there 4 lists in generator..how can i include the other two lists.@SlaterTyranus

Comment: @user3226258 You just need to use the above function *exactly* the way it's written. I just tried that exact example and it worked fine. You shouldn't change it at all. If you changed the input to `seq1, seq2, *args`, then `*args` only refers to the last two inputs.